# After clone(), function is not working. jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wanted when i click the button it should turn into text and clone new button.After clone object executed. Function is not working. Here is my code

**jQuery**

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $(this).replaceWith('<p>'+ $(this).text() +'</p>');
  $(this).clone().appendTo('body');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tuxsanov/bk5tF/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).on('click','button', function(){
 $(this).replaceWith('<p>'+ $(this).text() +'</p>');
 $(this).clone().appendTo('body');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bk5tF/2/)**

Comment: what is the differences using with event delegation ?